# Friend of Follow Other Stack Users

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is there any way to friend other stack exchange users? My friend and I could not find this option on our profiles.

Answer (score 13):

No such feature exists, Stack Exchange is not a social network. You should be able to keep track of your friends without a list in the system.

Answer (score 1):

3ventic is correct that there is no "friend" or "follow" features and likely will not be.  To see more discussion on that, check out [this meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/225764).

If you want to follow users for some reason (maybe you like reading their questions/answers) there is one fairly easy way.  On a user's profile, in the bottom right corner, there is an RSS feed for that user.